# Session data is not propagated to the next request

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

There's a problem with Codeigniter I can't get to fix. When I log in successfully and create the necessary session variables, the redirection in the next request can't retrieve those variables. The **$_SESSION** var doesn't have them!

This is the code executed just when someone submits user and password to log in:

```
$data = array(
    'user'      => $this->input->post('user'),
    'password'  => $this->input->post('password'),
);

// Trying to log in
try{
    // Validation ....

    // Users instance creation ....
    $this->user = (...)

    // Last action before the redirection
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'user'          => serialize($this->user),
                'logged_in'     => true,
                'last_access'       => time(),
                'session_max_time'  => config_item('app_sess_expiration'),
        ));

    // At this point, if I do a var_dump($_SESSION), it will display all my session variables as expected.

    redirect(base_url());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Not reaching this code
    $data['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    redirect_to_login();
}
```

Now if I **var_dump($_SESSION)** right after session_start() in *system/libraries/Session/Session.php* it will only display, on the redirection request:

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1499021453
)
```

My own session variables are missing!

I've checked that everytime I try to authenticate, a new session variable is created:

```
luis@luis-pc ~ $ ls -la /opt/lampp/temp
total 20312
drwxrwxrwx  2 daemon daemon    24576 jul  2 21:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 root   root       4096 jun 19 22:37 ..
-rw-------  1 daemon daemon 20735126 jun 20 22:14 phpjtS2zn
-rw-------  1 daemon daemon       34 jul  2 20:50 session_myapp51697449f5b8d526ee2cce05a5149135e3c1d74f
-rw-------  1 daemon daemon      785 jul  2 21:16 session_myapp72d8e8c189283c1d5c5d4ed60d7dd58ed5d9d69c
-rw-------  1 daemon daemon       34 jul  2 21:16 session_myapp9a97c65cda1c846028fc3035abe5023a73cf974b
-rw-------  1 daemon daemon       34 jul  2 21:16 session_myappf122822e7c8887b14239eb9e97d70266d47c658b
-rw-------  1 daemon daemon    14891 jul  2 21:15 sess_50fbaf84f2b49bf7c176b8c0396c099e
```

I'm not sure if the file permissions might have something to do. I gave read permissions to all users in the temp directory, but all the session files are created with owner-only permissions. However I think daemon is the owner of the run process too, isn't it? So the session file should be retrieved.

**EDIT 1:**

This is my session set up in the config.php file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'session_myapp';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = "/opt/lampp/temp";
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Have you though about using codeigniter form validation https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: CI Sessions are separate to PHP Sessions. They are stored either in a file you define or in a database table. So what is your CI Sessions configuration settings from your config.php file?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I use the file storage option. I've added the session config lines as you asked for.

Comment: I think you are confused... You should only use either $_SESSION or CI's Sessions. They are different... If you are setting a session var using CI Sessions It will NOT appear in $_SESSION... So if you are using CI sessions you can view those using something like var_dump($this->session->userdata());

Comment: Plus your Session save path should be local to your Document root. You are trying to write sessions to a system folder requiring root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['user'] && $_POST['password'])

{ 

$this->session->set_userdata(array(

'user'          => serialize($this->user),
'logged_in'     => true,
'last_access'       => time(),
'session_max_time'  => config_item('app_sess_expiration'),
));
}
```

Comment: I have $_POST['user'] and $_POST['password'] when I set the session data

Comment: set session only if POST value passed from previous page.Otherwise session value will be saved as empty.So i recommend try the above code.....

Comment: As I told you, POST is already populated when I set the session variables. I do a validation to check it, in which case an exception is thrown and catched. I omitted the validation because it's not relevant (there's only a comment mentioning it).

Answer (score 0):

you must put query before create session .. something like this;

```
if($query->num_array() > 0){


//create your own session data ..

}
```

also be sure you put this in config/autoload

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

and try another browser, or clear your browser cookies and try again.

Comment: I already added the session library to the autoloader, and I'm using the file storage configuration for the session, not a database.